# Store date in dd-mm-yyyy format or dd.mm.yyyy format in SQL Server (AWS RDS Distribution)

Tags: sql-server, date, formatting

I'm migrating data from DB2 for Z/os (Mainframe) to RDS distribution of SQL Server.

In the mainframe, the date is stored in EURO format which is DD.MM.YYYY, when I migrate the data to SQL Server, the data is stored in SQL Server in YYYY-MM-DD ISO format.

All of my application program expects the date to be in DD.YY.MMMM format. I know I can use convert function at application programs to format the date to convert to EURO format. There are thousands of programs which would require change if I take that route.

Is there a way I can enforce SQL Server to store the date in DD.MM.YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY format ?

I already tried changing the Default Language of SQL server to "British English" it doesn't seem to be of any help. When I issue "DBCC USEROPTIONS" it shows Language as "BRITISH" and Date as 'dmy' but still when application program retrieves the date it's in yyyy-mm-dd format only.

My application program connects to SQL Server via ODBC driver and I have tried changing the OS Date from Control panel as well of dd/mm/yyyy format. Any advice on this issue will be of great help.

Thanks in advance!

I already tried changing the Default Language of SQL server to "British English" it doesn't seem to be of any help. When I issue "DBCC USEROPTIONS" it shows Language as "BRITISH" and Date as 'dmy' but still when application program retrieves the date it's in yyyy-mm-dd format only.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't store the date in any particular format - it's stored as **binary data**. The formattting only happens when you fetch the data, and display it in a management tool (like SSMS), or in your application. So you cannot "enforce" SQL Server to any particular format - since there is none.....

Comment: Thanks Marc.... So is there a way that I can default the Date value to be returned in DD.MM.YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY format from the server rather than having to change  Application Code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee that that dates are returned as dd.mm.yyyy, then you can convert them to a string:

```
select convert(char(10), datecol, 104)
```

In SQL Server, you can handle this by using views or adding computed columns to the tables:

```
alter table d add datecol_ddmmyyyy as ( convert(char(10), datecol, 104) );
```

Otherwise, the application should be able to ingest SQL Server dates *in the native format*.  This is only relevant if they are being converted to strings.